# How to find the Ext js component having double qoutes in text using Ext.ComponentQuery.query

Tags: extjs

I have a Button in Ext JS which has text property =

```html
<span class="g-underlined">S</span>earch
```

I am writing the query as below :

```js
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text="<span class=\"g-underlined\">S</span>earch"]');
```

But i am unable to find the component

Comment: You should really give your button an `itemId` or something - your approach isn't really that robust, and what happens when you decide you want to internationalize or otherwise alter the language / visual appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text=<span class="g-underlined">S</span>earch]');
```

Answer (score 0):

To query elements we have another function

```
 Ext.select('.g-underlined');
```

it will returns all the elements which have that class.